# Can I use a link rel publisher tag in the head of both of my business websites to connect them to my Google business page?

Tags: google-maps, seo, google-plus

To connect my website to my Google business page, I should add
`<link href="https://plus.google.com/xxx" rel="publisher">`.

But I have 2 pages because I have 2 different addresses.  Should I add both of them?  Which one will show up on the search results?

My final goal here is to show my business info on the right side of the search results.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two physical locations for your business there's no reason you couldn't have two G+ pages, each linked to the (domain?) for that business. If you have a single domain with two unique pages for each location. Think of those as author pages on a blog where each author page is linked to it's own G+ page. Do you have unique domains, or two unique pages on a single domain?